# Use of "compute" and "calculate"

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between "computation" and "calculation"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10316/difference-between-computation-and-calculation)

> Speed is calculated/computed as distance per time.
>   Speed is a quotient ratio of distance and time.

"Calculated" and "computed" can be used interchangeably, can't they ? In the first and the second sentences, which one is correct?

Comment: did you mean :"Speed is a quotient/ratio of distance and time."?

Comment: I imagine the votes to close are because most dictionaries define these two words in very similar terms. This doesn't prove there's *no difference* between them.

Comment: @Baby Dolphin You can add a comment and clarify what you meant with the second question. As it is now, quotient ratio is redundant.

Comment: @Bogdan Lătăianu: I didn't intend to endorse the apparent tautology, just correct the obvious typo.

Comment: Another word with a similar meaning is "tally".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was surprised to find that **computed** hasn't obviously become more common since computers became more widespread. In fact, **calculated** continues to be used more often...
[image]

At first I thought they might even be a rare example of [true synonyms](http://german.about.com/library/blthesaurus.htm), but there are "idiomatic" contexts where only one word is used.

- *does not compute* sometimes means *makes no sense* (always in the negative).
- *calculate* sometimes means *think, consider, believe* (with no arithmetic involved).

Comment: why is everybody except me ignoring the quotient/ratio thing?

Comment: @Bogdan Lătăianu: Ah, well, I'm not really a mathematician. I can see there is such a thing as a [quotient ratio method](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12175167), but I'm not sure if there are any other meanings for ratio, such that it might make sense to specifically speak of a *quotient ratio* as opposed to some other kind.

Answer (score 1):

My local dictionary offers these definitions:

> compute — calculate or reckon (a figure or amount)
>
> calculate — determine (the amount or number of something)

So yes, they are entirely interchangeable.

Comment: Oops! I now regret upvoting, since realising there are idiomatic usages that only occur with one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

The meanings of *compute* are essentially:

- calculate or reckon a figure or amount
- make a calculation, especially using a computer
- (informal, used with negative) seem reasonable; make sense

The meanings of *calculate* are:

- determine the amount or number of something mathematically
- determine by reasoning, experience, or common sense; reckon or judge
- include as an essential element in one's plans

There is an overlapping between the meaning of the two words, and it is probable that many people don't use *calculate* only for a calculation made with a computer.